# PHP Form/Post Output

Tags: php

The **HTML** page

```
<form action="test2.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and the **test2.php**

```
<?php
$firstname = $_POST['name'];
print("Name $firstname");
?>
```

and it shows error

> **Notice: Undefined index: firstname in test2.php on line 7**

This is a problem when i run it on my PHPstorm. PHP i am using is v7.1.3

I don't know whats wrong.

**INSERTING PICS**

[image: HTML File]
[image: PHP File]

This was using XAMPP and still same results

Comment: can you tell me which statement is on line 7 ?

Comment: Wrap it in an isset(), it will only be set after pressing submit

Comment: @TusharNiras this is $firstname= $_POST['name'];

Comment: @Mihai when i try that nothing appears as output

Comment: make sure **name** input fild is properly submitted to **welcome.php** page. Try `print_r($_POST);` on welcome.php

Comment: >Notice: Undefined index: firstname in C:\Users\rabhi\PhpstormProjects\test2\test2.php on line 7
Array ( )

@TusharNiras Now this is the output after using print_r($_POST)

Comment: this is running completely fine in Netbeans.

Comment: I tried it without phpstorm  and in bracket. Still no output

Comment: Works fine in XAMPP.

Comment: failed in wamp will try in XAMPP

Comment: Still didn't work in XAMPP. THIS IS FRUSTRATING. If this step doesn't work i CANNOT progress. Is there any other step that i  missed.

Answer (score 0):

Check your variable defined or not in following method

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $firstname = $_POST['name'];
   echo "Name ".$firstname;    
}
```

Comment: No errors. But there is no output either. :(
I can't understand what the problem is.